# Solve equation with two unknowns (maybe modulo)

Tags: problem-solving

Given the following equation: $$   x^{2} - y^{2}=17, \quad 0\neq x,y\in \mathbb N$$

I know for example that one solution is $x=9$, $y=8$,
but I do not know how to get it.

Comment: Hint: Can you factorise $x^2-y^2$?

Comment: As long as I get appropriate solution for the equation.

Answer (score 1):

rewrite your equation in the form
$(x-y)(x+y)=1\cdot 17$
from here you will get
$x-y=1$ and $x+y=17$ the other case is impossible.
or we have
$(x-y)(x+y)=(-1)\cdot (-17)$

Comment: But how is that help me ?

Comment: $2x = 18$ by adding the two equations together!

Comment: @Dr. Sonnhard Graubner: In that case I get a single solution. That means no more solutions in N ?